# How to include array of struct defined in another header in C?

Tags: arrays, c, struct, header-files

I have the below files:

- `swaps.c`:

```
#include "swaps.h"
#include "./poolutils.h"

double someFunction(struct Pool pools[]){
//do some stuff
}

int main(){
struct Pool pool1 = {"A","C",3.0,9000.0,0.0};
struct Pool pool2 = {"B","D",20.0,20000,0.0};
struct Pool pools[N];
pools[0] = pool1;
pools[1] = pool2;
double a = someFunction(pools);
}
```

- `swaps.h` has signature of `someFunction`
- `poolutils.c` has some functions
- `poolutils.h`:

```
#ifndef _POOLUTILS_H
#define _POOLUTILS_H

struct Pool {
    char *token1;
    char *token2;
    double reserve1;
    double reserve2;
    double fee;
};
//signatures of poolutils.c functions 
#endif
```

When compiling (`gcc -c swaps.c poolutils.c`), I am getting the below error:

```
In file included from swaps.c:1:
swaps.h:4:44: error: array type has incomplete element type ‘struct Pool’
    4 | double someFunction(struct Pool pools[]);
```

Now, I do include the header where the `struct Pool` is defined, so `swaps.c` should know about it but I understand that somehow `swaps.h` does not, how can I make it aware of the outside definitions ?

(gcc version 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6))

Comment: do not place data instances in header files.  Because those data elements will be generated in each .c file that includes that header file.   It will fail during the linking and/or running steps due to duplicate definitions of the data,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add

```
#include "./poolutils.h"
```

to your `swaps.h` too, if `swaps.h` needs the `Pool` struct definition.

Since you've dutifully put include guards in `poolutils.h`, you can use the header multiple times in a single compilation unit.

Alternately, swap the order of your includes; the effect is the same here.

```
#include "./poolutils.h"
#include "swaps.h"
```

Comment: Which option is the cleanest/recommended?

Comment: Depending on the size of your program, I'd probably split type/structure definitions into a separate header file you can include wherever. Beyond that, the first option; anything that depends on you having to know the correct order for your includes is bound to be brittle.

Comment: Alternatively, if all functions/types don't use `struct Pool` but rather a pointer to it like `struct Pool*` but **not** `struct Pool []` then you could just place a forward declaration: `struct Pool;`